# Count of array values

Tags: php, arrays

Need exact count of values in array.
My result is :

```
stdClass Object ( [employee] => ["1","2"] )
```

I want the count value as 2. Is it possible ?

My laravel query :

```
$work = DB::table('workingdat')
            ->select(DB::raw('employee'))
            ->get();
            $work->toArray($work);
            print_r($work);
```

I was store JSON data in my table under the column employee.
Example : ["1","2"]

Comment: what do you mean by count value as 2 ? you can have `count()` to calculate the total values

Comment: There is a `count($classInstance->employee)` function.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your object into an array and then use the count() function of php
For example:

```
$arr = array($your_object);
echo count($arr);
```

Comment: result is 1... I want the result as 2. based on two values in that array

Comment: Make sure you type cast the object and please submit your code so that it is possible to  understand more clearly

Comment: Ok I ll add my query in my question

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to typecast your abject into an array.

```
$array =  (array) $yourObject;
```

refer this link also : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

after typecast you can count array value like this.

```
echo $total = count($array['employee']);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this object, as illustrated in your question.

```
<?php
$object = new StdClass();
$object->employee = array(1, 2);
```

You can get the count like this:

```
<?php
$count = count($object->employee); // 2
```

Comment: stdClass Object ( [employee] => Illuminate\Support\Collection Object ( [items:protected] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [employee] => ["1","2"] ) ) ) )

Comment: @LingamDiaz I see. So it's not a StdClass object, it's a support collection in Laravel, and the items are protected. To get the count, simply use the `count()` method. See: https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_count

Comment: i.e., `$object->employee->count()`